# Prove or disprove: there exists a function s.t $f'(x)=-f^2(x)$ for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$ and $f(x)\ne0\space$ for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hey I've got this question, and I really don't even know where to start, here it goes:

PROVE or DISPROVE:  There exists a function $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}\space$ such that $f'(x)=-f^2(x)$
for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$ and such that $f(x)\ne0\space$ for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$.

My feeling is that there isn't one, and so I thought of assuming contradiction and then calculating some integral to get a contradiction (maybe since $\int \frac{f'(x)}{-f^2(x)}dx=1$ and $f(x)\ne0$), but this is based only on a sort of similar exercise we had in class..

any help much appreciated!

Comment: The condition $f'(x) = - f(x)^2$ is a differential equation. To simplify set $y=f(x)$ and write it as $\frac{dy}{dx} = -y^2$ and so $\frac{dy}{y^2} = -dx$. Suppose that $y(0) = \alpha$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary. Now solve this initial value problem. You will observe that the solution of this problem is never zero but its domain can not be equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$-\dfrac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}=1\Rightarrow \bigg(\dfrac{1}{f(x)}\bigg)'=(x)'$ so $\dfrac{1}{f(x)}=x+c,\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ so $\dfrac{1}{f(-c)}=0$ contradiction

Comment: simple and elegant, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

if f is not 0 identically, then
$\frac{1}{f(x)}=\int \frac{f'(x)}{-f^2(x)}dx=\int dx=x+C$.
Then we get $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+C}$.

f is not defined for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$. Therefore there is no function $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}\space$ such that $f'(x)=-f^2(x)$
for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$ and such that $f(x)\ne0\space$ for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$.